# check if datetime is the same across ID's after grouping by other columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Below is a table with 4 columns:
Place(object type)
Dates (datetime)
id (object type)
event_datetime(datetime)

| Place | dates | id | event_datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 2022-01-03 | 1234 | 2022-01-03 14:42:56 |
| bbb | 2022-03-16 | 4567 | 2022-03-16 15:31:00 |
| bbb | 2022-03-16 | 4567 | 2022-03-16 16:13:28 |
| bbb | 2022-03-16 | 7890 | 2022-03-16 15:31:00 |
| bbb | 2022-03-16 | 7890 | 2022-03-16 16:13:28 |
| ccc | 2021-09-12 | 2345 | 2021-09-12 08:01:48 |
| ccc | 2021-09-12 | 5486 | 2021-09-12 08:02:38 |

My task is to 1) group by place and dates and if there is more than 1 unique ID, then check if all the event_datetimes are the same. This could be done at the hour and min level and doesn't need to include seconds. The result could be in a new column `Check` that could have values "Yes" and "No".

For example, group place 'bbb' and date '2022-03-16', there are two ID's, '4567', '7890'. We can see that these two IDs have same event_datetimes '2022-03-16 15:31:00', '2022-03-16 16:13:28'. Therefore, the final `Check` column should say yes.

Whereas, for group 'ccc' and date '2021-09-12', the event_datetimes for the ID's are not the same therefore, the `check` column should say no.

Final output:

| Place | dates | id | event_datetime | Check |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 2022-01-03 | 1234 | 2022-01-03 14:42:56 | no |
| bbb | 2022-03-16 | 4567 | 2022-03-16 15:31:00 | yes |
| bbb | 2022-03-16 | 4567 | 2022-03-16 16:13:28 | yes |
| bbb | 2022-03-16 | 7890 | 2022-03-16 15:31:00 | yes |
| bbb | 2022-03-16 | 7890 | 2022-03-16 16:13:28 | yes |
| ccc | 2021-09-12 | 2345 | 2021-09-12 08:01:48 | no |
| ccc | 2021-09-12 | 5486 | 2021-09-12 08:02:38 | no |

I appreciate any help or advice.

```
d = {'Place': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ccc'],
        'dates': ['2022-01-03', '2022-03-16', '2022-03-16', 
                  '2022-03-16', '2022-03-16', '2021-09-12',
                 '2021-09-12'],
       'id': ['1234', '4567', '4567',
                 '7890', '7890', '2345', 
                 '2345'],
     'event_date_time': ['2022-01-03 14:42:56', '2022-03-16 15:31:00', '2022-03-16 16:13:28', 
                  '2022-03-16 15:31:00', '2022-03-16 16:13:28', '2021-09-12 08:01:48',
                 '2021-09-12 08:01:48']
    }
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(d)
sample_df['event_date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(sample_df['event_date_time'])
sample_df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(sample_df['dates'])
sample_df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` with `duplicated`:

```
cols = ["Place", "id"]
m = df.groupby(cols)["event_datetime"].agg(set).duplicated(keep=False)
new_df = df.merge(m.rename("Check"), left_on=cols, right_index=True)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
  Place       dates    id       event_datetime  Check
0   aaa  2022-01-03  1234  2022-01-03 14:42:56  False
1   bbb  2022-03-16  4567  2022-03-16 15:31:00   True
2   bbb  2022-03-16  4567  2022-03-16 16:13:28   True
3   bbb  2022-03-16  7890  2022-03-16 15:31:00   True
4   bbb  2022-03-16  7890  2022-03-16 16:13:28   True
5   ccc  2021-09-12  2345  2021-09-12 08:01:48  False
6   ccc  2021-09-12  5486  2021-09-12 08:02:38  False
```